# Boost Spirit, obtain iterator inside semantic action

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

within a semantic action I want to get the iterator, preferably the entire iterator range from the first to last parsed character. When using the `raw` directive I could simply get it with `_attr(context)`. I guessed that `_where(context)` does this, but it only returns an empty range whose begin iterator points to the character after the parsed substring.

Sample code:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

int main()
{
    const auto action = [](auto &ctx)
    {
        auto range = x3::_where(ctx);
        std::cout << range.size() << '\n';
        std::cout << "range start: " << static_cast<const void*>(&*range.begin()) << '\n';
    };

    const auto rule = x3::int_[action];

    const std::string input = "432";
    std::cout << "string start: " << static_cast<const void*>(input.data()) << '\n';

    int output;
    x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), rule, x3::space, output);
    std::cout << output << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
string start: 0x7ffd65f337c0
0
range start: 0x7ffd65f337c3
432
```

The length of the range is 0 and begin() of it points to the end of string. When I expand the input string the range covers the remaining unparsed substring.

How can I get the iterator range that contains the parsed substring?

Comment: It's pretty useful to actually show some code. I know I've had this working fine, so perhaps something would stand out about your code. Right now you'll have to hope I'll be bored enough to come up with a reproducer myself and then answer.

Comment: Okay, I'll be right back with some code.

Comment: Code added now.

Comment: Excellent, I added my ideas on the subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, seeing your code made me remember what I did in the past.

Basically, you can

1. use `on_error` handling on an `x3::rule<>` and it will give you the matched iterator range. See for an example:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/596c9119db0e9f46)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <utility>
   #include <iomanip>

   namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

   namespace {
       struct ehbase {
           template <typename It, typename Attr, typename Ctx>
               void on_success(It& f, It const& l, Attr const& attr, Ctx const& /*ctx*/) const {
                   std::cout << "on_succes: " << std::quoted(std::string(f, l)) << " -> " << attr << "\n";
               }
       };

       struct rule_type : ehbase {};
   }

   int main() {
       const auto rule = x3::rule<rule_type, int>{"rule"} = x3::int_;

       for (std::string const input : { "q", "432", " 646 q" }) {
           std::cout << "== " << std::quoted(input) << " ==\n";
           auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
           int output;
           if (x3::phrase_parse(f, l, rule, x3::space, output))
               std::cout << "Parsed " << output << "\n";
           else
               std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

           if (f!=l)
               std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
       }
   }
   ```

   Prints

   ```
   == "q" ==
   Parse failed
   Remaining: "q"
   == "432" ==
   on_succes: "432" -> 432
   Parsed 432
   == " 646 q" ==
   on_succes: "646" -> 646
   Parsed 646
   Remaining: "q"
   ```

   > On a slight tangent, you can add error-handling in the same vein:
   >
   > ```
   > template <typename It, typename Ctx>
   > x3::error_handler_result on_error(It f, It l, x3::expectation_failure<It> const& e, Ctx const& /*ctx*/) const {
   >     std::cout << std::string(f,l) << "\n"
   >               << std::setw(1+std::distance(f, e.where())) << "^"
   >               << "-- expected: " << e.which() << "\n";
   >     return x3::error_handler_result::fail;
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > If you have an expectation point in the parser:
   >
   > ```
   > const auto rule = x3::rule<rule_type, int>{"rule"} = x3::int_ > x3::eoi;
   > ```
   >
   > It now prints: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bc4feeb3768d7f6)</kbd>**
   >
   > ```
   > == " 646 q" ==
   >  646 q
   >      ^-- expected: eoi
   > Parse failed
   > Remaining: "646 q"
   > ```
2. You can use the `x3::raw[]` directive to expose an iterator range as the attribute:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5de6cdea6f5241d)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <utility>
   #include <iomanip>

   namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

   int main() {
       for (std::string const input : { "q", "432", " 646 q" }) {
           std::cout << "== " << std::quoted(input) << " ==\n";

           auto action = [&input](auto& ctx) {
               auto iters = x3::_attr(ctx);
               std::cout
                   << input << "\n"
                   << std::setw(std::distance(input.begin(), iters.begin())) << ""
                   << "^ matched: " <<  std::quoted(std::string(iters.begin(), iters.end())) << "\n";
           };

           const auto rule = x3::raw[x3::int_] [action];

           auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
           if (x3::phrase_parse(f, l, rule, x3::space))
               std::cout << "Parse succeeded\n";
           else
               std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

           if (f!=l)
               std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
       }
   }
   ```

   Prints:

   ```
   == "q" ==
   Parse failed
   Remaining: "q"
   == "432" ==
   432
   ^ matched: "432"
   Parse succeeded
   == " 646 q" ==
    646 q
    ^ matched: "646"
   Parse succeeded
   Remaining: "q"
   ```

   > Again, slightly related, it can become a little more cumbersome to deal with attribute propagation in this approach:
   >
   > ```
   > const auto rule
   >     = x3::rule<struct _rule, int, true> {"rule"}
   >     = &x3::raw[x3::int_] [action] >> x3::int_;;
   >
   > auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
   > int output;
   > if (x3::phrase_parse(f, l, rule, x3::space, output))
   > ```
3. To alleviate the clumsy attribute propagation, you might write a custom parser component that simply wraps another and adds the logic you want:

   ```
   template <typename SubjectParser>
   struct verbose : x3::parser<verbose<SubjectParser> > {
       explicit verbose(SubjectParser p, std::string name) : _subject(std::move(p)), _name(std::move(name)) {}

       SubjectParser _subject;
       std::string _name;

       template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename... Other>
       bool parse(It& f, It l, Ctx& ctx, Other&&... args) const {
           auto saved = f;
           auto ok = x3::as_parser(_subject).parse(f, l, ctx, std::forward<Other>(args)...);

           if (ok) {
               //optionally adjust for skipper
               x3::skip_over(saved, l, ctx);
               std::cout << "Debug: " << _name << " matched " << std::quoted(std::string(saved, f)) << "\n";
           }
           return ok;
       }
   };
   ```

   Now wrapping the parser expression like this:

   ```
   const auto rule = verbose {x3::int_, "YUMMY"};
   ```

   Results in the following output: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b76787c26dbf0b50)</kbd>**

   ```
   == "q" ==
   Parse failed
   Remaining: "q"
   == "432" ==
   Debug: YUMMY matched "432"
   Parsed 432
   == " 646 q" ==
   Debug: YUMMY matched "646"
   Parsed 646
   Remaining: "q"
   ```
4. Distilling it to that, made me realize that rule-debugging could have been /all that you were looking for/. In which case, simply using `BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG` could be what you needed to know:

   **<kbd>[[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47c240452c321219)</kbd>**

   ```
   #define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
   #include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
   #include <iomanip>

   namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

   int main() {
       const auto rule 
           = x3::rule<struct _rule, int> {"rule"}
           = x3::int_;

       for (std::string const input : { "q", "432", " 646 q" }) {
           std::cout << "== " << std::quoted(input) << " ==\n";

           auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
           int output;
           if (x3::phrase_parse(f, l, rule, x3::space, output))
               std::cout << "Parsed " << output << "\n";
           else
               std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

           if (f!=l)
               std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
       }
   }
   ```

   Which prints:

   ```
   == "q" ==
   <rule>
     <try>q</try>
     <fail/>
   </rule>
   Parse failed
   Remaining: "q"
   == "432" ==
   <rule>
     <try>432</try>
     <success></success>
     <attributes>432</attributes>
   </rule>
   Parsed 432
   == " 646 q" ==
   <rule>
     <try> 646 q</try>
     <success> q</success>
     <attributes>646</attributes>
   </rule>
   Parsed 646
   Remaining: "q"
   ```